# UML Class Diagram "can be" relationship

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram

I have two classes – *Type* and *Model*.

A *Type* can be primitive, but any *Model* can be further used as a *Type*. Hence, a *Type* **can be** a *Model*, but **doesn't have to be**.

How do I represent this using a UML Class Diagram?

My initial idea is to also define a *PrimitiveType* and then connect that class and the *Model* class to the *Type* using a generalization, but I can't help but assume there is a better way.

Comment: _Model can be [...] used as a Type. [...] Type can be a Model_ sounds weird. Which one is the base?

Comment: @qwerty_so Consider an OO programming language. You can have a variable of primitive type (`int x = 5`)  or define a model (Class) which can be further used as a type (`MyClass x = new MyClass()`). What I'm trying to represent is similar to this – a *Type* can be either *Primitive* or *Model*. Furthermore, a *Model* can have *Parameters* of any *Type*.

Comment: Your are mixing definitions. You should go to square one and write down what is what. Define the terms Type and Model. Once you did that you will have your answer. `int x` is _not_ a Type it _has_ a type.

Comment: @qwerty_so `x` indeed *has* a type, but `int` *is* a type. And so *is* `MyClass`. But I will model `int` differently than `MyClass`, since `int` won't have properties, for example, which `MyClass` will. That's why I need a different concept for `int` (*PrimitiveType*) and `MyClass` (*Model*).

Comment: Since you did not clarify your question I voted to close it.

Comment: Don't thank me. Edit your question...

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted. It would give me some credit points. If you are not satisfied, please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One generalization is enough. The arrow should point from Model to Type, which means: a Model is a Type. All Models are Types, but not all Types are Models.

[image: cd]

By default, a superclass is not abstract, i.e. instances of the superclass may exist. For example, if `File` is a superclass and `Image File` and `Text File` are the only subclasses, then there are three kinds of Files: Images Files, Text Files and Files that are neither Image Files nor Text Files. However, if `File` is declared as an *abstract* superclass, then all Files are either Image Files or Text Files.